# Can I use Javascript string object methods on jQuery .text()

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

Would like to manipulate some text upon a click:

```
$('.Jserep').change(function () {
    $(".Jappended").text().replace("&lt;serep&gt;Y&lt;/serep&gt;", 'serep&gt;N&lt;/serep&gt;')
});
```

But it doesn't work. Does .text() return a native string object that I can use replace on?

Comment: Please be more specific than "*... But it doesn't work...*"

Comment: can you add a fiddle, because `.text()` returns a string and your code should work

Answer (score 4):

```
$(".Jappended").text($(".Jappended").text().replace("&lt;serep&gt;Y&lt;/serep&gt;", 'serep&gt;N&lt;/serep&gt;'))
```

Assign the result to the text

Answer (score 1):

The reason what you're doing doesn't work is you're not using the result anywhere. `replace` returns a **new** string with the replacements done. What you're doing is equivalent to this:

```
var str = "hi there";
str.replace("hi", "bye");
```

...which does the work but doesn't store it anywhere. You'd need

```
var str = "hi there";
str = str.replace("hi", "bye");
```

Note how we're using the return value of `replace` there.

So assuming that `$(".Jappended")` only matches a single element:

```
var elm = $(".Jappended");
elm.text(elm.text().replace("&lt;serep&gt;Y&lt;/serep&gt;", 'serep&gt;N&lt;/serep&gt;'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should receive a native string.

> The result of the .text() method is a string containing the combined
>   text of all matched elements.

[Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

**Example:**

```
var text = $("#test").text();
alert(typeof text); //outputs string
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VG4ft/)

Answer (score 0):

According to the Api: Yes.
http://api.jquery.com/text/
"Get the combined text contents of each element in the set of matched elements, including their descendants, or set the text contents of the matched elements."
But according to your code, you receive the string, do the replacements, but never insert the string anywhere. The result would simply be garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is this:

```
$('.Jserep').change(function () {
    var newText = $(".Jappended").text().replace("&lt;serep&gt;Y&lt;/serep&gt;", 'serep&gt;N&lt;/serep&gt;');
    $(".Jappended").text(newText);
});
```

Or more simply:

```
$('.Jserep').change(function () {
    var el = $(".Jappended");
    el.text(el[0].replace("&lt;serep&gt;Y&lt;/serep&gt;", 'serep&gt;N&lt;/serep&gt;'));
});
```

Or even more simply

```
$(".Jappended").text(function() {return this.innerTextreplace("&lt;serep&gt;Y&lt;/serep&gt;", 'serep&gt;N&lt;/serep&gt;')});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.Jserep').change(function () {
    $(".Jappended").text($(".Jappended").text().replace("&lt;serep&gt;Y&lt;/serep&gt;", 'serep&gt;N&lt;/serep&gt;'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this :

```
$(".Jappended").text(function (i,n){return n.replace("&lt;serep&gt;Y&lt;/serep&gt;", 'serep&gt;N&lt;/serep&gt;');});
```

using this overload :

[image]

No need to open new variables nor calling `text()` twice  etc.

Use what the API **already** provides

Answer (score 0):

As you told, on click of text you want to change text, but then why you using

```
$('.Jserep').change(
```

It should be .click() event right. as @billyonecan told you can use replace on it.

Hope this answered your question

Comment: sorry i didn't include that it was checkbox I was clicking. and i didn't want the event to happen if the checkbox was unchecked. miscomm